# Why there another value of Xmx VM Options when launch embeded maven in intellj

Tags: java, performance, maven, intellij-idea, jvm

I am trying to understand where and how the memory vm options are setted and used

In my environnment i have setted the vm options for maven in the MAVEN_OPTS env variable
[image]

and the intellij vm options in the idea64.vmoptions 
[image]

and the embeded maven vm options in the settings of intellij
[image]

We can see the values of these variable in the ide workspace file 
[image]

I have configured a maven runner goal with vm options too 
[image]

I have set different values to know which one is used, but i am wondering why when i execute the maven goal it set a value (Xmx1024M) that i never set anywhere before setting the vm options that i set in the runner goal (MaxmetaspaceSize=2213M) 
[image]

So i am trying to understand from where this value is taken

Edit :
Here is the Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Running Tests options : 
[image]

But the behaviour didn't change

Sorry for my english
Many thanks

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS` system environment variables set?

Comment: @CrazyCoder no i d'ont have any JAVA options in my system variable environnment

Comment: Do you use maven `surefire` or `failsafe` plugins? IDE take the arg line from these plugins's configuration if corresponding options are enabled in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Running Tests** options.

Comment: You can test it also by running Maven from command line and check this option.

Comment: @Andrey yes i do use the surefire and failsafe plugins, i tried to uncheck all the checkbox in :  Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Running Tests options. but this does not change anything

When run maven from the command line i cannot see the system variable used

Comment: Do you see the same -Xmx setting when you run Maven build outside of IntelliJ IDEA in the terminal?